# Add Views to EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I want to customize EditText in android and want to add Views/Layouts to it. Please suggest me some tutorial or any source code which will help me.

Comment: You can't add Views to EditText, you will have to build your own custom  `EditText like` Layout.

Comment: `EditText` is not a `ViewGroup`, so I don't even think this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Adding views to `EditText` is not possible. But you can create a *Custom component*.

Please have a look at the Google's tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html